# Is there an idiomatic way to order function arguments in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Seems like it's inconsistent in the lists module.  For example, split has the number as the first argument and the list as the second, but sublists has the list as the first argument and the len as the second argument.

Comment: No, its a mess because the libraries werent so much designed as they evolved. Await rvirding's answer and follow his style. :)

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm coming from an OO background, but it seems that all the functions that operate on lists should take the list as the first argument

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, a little history as I remember it and some principles behind my style.

As Christian has said the libraries evolved and tended to get the argument order and feel from the impulses we were getting just then. So for example the reason why element/setelement have the argument order they do is because it matches the arg/3 predicate in Prolog; logical then but not now. Often we would have the *thing* being worked on first, but unfortunately not always. This is often a good choice as it allows "optional" arguments to be conveniently added to the end; for example string:substr/2/3. Functions with the *thing* as the last argument were often influenced by functional languages with currying, for example Haskell, where it is very easy to use currying and partial evaluation to build specific functions which can then be applied to the *thing*. This is very noticeable in the higher order functions in lists.

The only influence we didn't have was from the OO world. :-)

Usually we at least managed to be consistent within a module, but not always. See lists again. We did try to have some consistency, so the argument order in the higher order functions in dict/sets match those of the corresponding functions in lists.

The problem was also aggravated by the fact that we, **especially me**, had a rather cavalier attitude to libraries. I just did not see them as a selling point for the language, so I wasn't that worried about it. "If you want a library which does something then you just write it" was my motto. This meant that my libraries were structured, just not always with the same structure. :-) That was how many of the initial libraries came about.

This, of course, creates unnecessary confusion and breaks the law of least astonishment, but we have not been able to do anything about it. Any suggestions of revising the modules have always been met with a resounding "no".

My own personal style is a usually structured, though I don't know if it conforms to any written guidelines or standards.

I generally have the *thing* or *things* I am working on as the first arguments, or at least very close to the beginning; the order depends on what feels best. If there is a global state which is chained through the whole module, which there usually is, it is placed as the last argument and given a very descriptive name like St0, St1, ... (I belong to the church of short variable names). Arguments which are chained through functions (both input and output) I try to keep the same argument order as return order. This makes it much easier to see the structure of the code. Apart from that I try to group together arguments which belong together. Also, where possible, I try to preserve the same argument order throughout a whole module.

None of this is very revolutionary, but I find if you keep a consistent style then it is one less thing to worry about and it makes your code feel better and generally be more readable. Also I will actually rewrite code if the argument order feels wrong.

A small example which may help:

```
fubar({f,A0,B0}, Arg2, Ch0, Arg4, St0) ->
    {A1,Ch1,St1} = foo(A0, Arg2, Ch0, St0),
    {B1,Ch2,St2} = bar(B0, Arg4, Ch1, St1),
    Res = baz(A1, B1),
    {Res,Ch2,St2}.
```

Here `Ch` is a local chained through variable while `St` is a more global state. Check out the code on github for LFE, especially the compiler, if you want a longer example.

This became much longer than it should have been, sorry.

P.S. I used the word *thing* instead of *object* to avoid confusion about what I was talking.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no consistently-used idiom in the sense that you mean.

However, there are some useful relevant hints that apply especially when you're going to be making deeply recursive calls.  For instance, keeping whichever arguments will remain unchanged during tail calls in the same order/position in the argument list allows the virtual machine to make some very nice optimizations.

Comment: Q: Where should I put my arguments? A: Arguments should remain where they are. Sounds like ancient wisdom :o)